# Authentication Error in Jenkins Send Mail

Tags: java, jenkins

SMTP server                                      **[myserverName]**
Default user e-mail suffix    **[myemailId]**
Use SMTP Authentication       **true**
User Name                                           **[myemailId]**
Password                                              **[mypassword]**
Use SSL                                                 **false**
SMTP Port                                             **25**
Reply-To Address                       **[myemailId]**
Test configuration by sending test e-mail     **[myemailId]**

I am using above configuration for sending mails using java and Jenkins version 1.579,
mail sent successfully using java but following exception came when tried to sent mail using Jenkins.

I have also created credentials in Jenkins, can you please assist me why Jenkins not able to validate user.

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication
>   unsuccessful  at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:809)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:752)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:669)
>     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)     at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)  at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)    at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)     at
>   hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.doSendTestMail(Mailer.java:519)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor280.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:120)   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:631)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:225)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
>     at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>     at
>   winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is a bug, check solution and suggestions here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24214